# Maven:How to exclude all thirdparty jar from web project source code?

Tags: java, maven, jboss, maven-2, jboss6.x

Currently we have a JSF Based web project which we are deploying in Jboss EAP 6.1 server.Its a multi-module project with plenty of third party jars added inside web-porject/lib folder.

When we run `mvn install` it create war file and we deploying this war file in Jboss but issue that its size is too big around 300MB.So sometime its hard for us deploy in war in the server if any single line changes in code its taking time upload the project in server.

We want we should separate out jar file(Third Party) and source code .So war size should be less and all third party jar should be seperate out from the source code.

This project is maven based project so all the dependency added in `pom.xml` file so for developer prospective we should not remove the pom file entry .

Can Someone please suggest what should be best way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You should do that in two steps.
First exclude dependencies from packaging and use them only for compilation phase:

```
  <dependencies>
    <!-- declare the dependency to be set as optional -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <optional>true</optional> <!-- value will be true or false only -->
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

In the second step put all the jars needed for running the application in jboss JBOSS_HOME/lib folder.

You can do that by using [Copying project dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html) maven plugin:

```
     <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: First step is ok but what about the putting jar in lib folder ,do you mean i have to put it manually? Like Copy-Paste from one location to another location then if any change if we will do in pom.xml file like add/delete dependency we have to again manually do everything ?

Comment: I suppose jars should be in JBOSS_HOME/common/lib

Comment: jboss-eap-6.1 dont have this folder structure then second thing this all we have to do manually ?

Comment: then I supose that lib folder will be ok

Comment: What about second question i asked and some changes in pom.xml file then again manually include/exclude jar from lib folder?

Comment: You can copy jars manually, or use https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html to copy dependencies by maven